# is there a way to embed swf files in facebook posts - November 2014

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

When fbml was supported by fb, you could use iframes but is there a way to conduct a survey style in a fb post with embedded swf files.

Because I develop using Adobe Flash Builder & Adobe Flex 4.6+?

Comment: Primarily I wanna know if there is a way to embed flash application/swf in fb posts?

Comment: Do you mean like we put a youtube player (video) ?

Comment: No, I'm not looking for video. Flash can do more than just Audio/Video things.

Comment: I know, but forget the content of youtube player, but that's what you need ? Share a swf on facebook ?!

Comment: @akmozo I's intended to use flash to conduct surveys with radio buttons.

Comment: YES of course you can do that ! I prepare an answer.

Comment: Facebook don't want to let the people advertise without money. They don't care for users safety.

Comment: Okay, @akmozo I'm waiting. But I will be able to test after November 15th, 2014.

Comment: I put an answer, take a look.

Comment: I'm going to sleep now. It's already 3:21 am here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can share content on facebook, to do that we use `Open Graph` tags which are included in your page’s HTML and allow the Facebook Crawler to generate previews when your content is shared on Facebook.

You can start here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects and If you have questions, I am here to help you.

Take this example :

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb">
   <meta property="og:type" content="game" />
   <meta property="og:url" content="http://your.site.com/page.html" />
   <meta property="og:title" content="title here" />
   <meta property="og:description" content="description here" />
   <meta property="og:image" content="http://your.site.com/image.jpg" />
   <meta property="og:video" content="https://your.https.site.com/your_swf.swf" />
   <meta property="og:video:width" content="480" />
   <meta property="og:video:height" content="360" />
   <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
</head>
```

This html code will give you an export like this :

[image: Facebook swf export example]

For more details you can also see : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/feed-gaming and for you debug on facebook, to verify if you get what you want, you can use facebook debug page here : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Comment: Gimme a link to non-video swf file in a post displayed like this one you shared.

Comment: sounds great. will look into it as soon as i can that if this technique still works... for the time being i'm working on another project currently. After that when i find time will dive again in to this thing. thanks a lot for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn´t possible, is like trying to post a gif on fb, it will only show the link

Comment: Are you sure buddy? I'm nearly gonna accept the fact: Facebook-Flash option.

Comment: -1, That's wrong, we can share images and other contents with text on fb.